# Installing elixir - I just get crashes

Tags: elixir, erl

I am trying to do my first "Hello World" in elixir. First step to just install it on my Macbook. I am doing:

```sh
brew update
brew install elixir
```

After that I can do:

```sh
erl --version
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source-d5c06c6] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.3  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

But when I try to get the elixir version...

```sh
elixir --version
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{elixir,start_cli,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

I tried doing uninstalls and reinstalls, brew update etc. I still get the same thing every time

Here is the [crash dump contents](https://pastebin.com/HeYJGDDS)

Comment: Use `asdf` versions manager, `brew` seems to have the ancient version and seemingly fails to install it properly.

Comment: Also, the error message looks like the version of [tag:elixir] was compiled against a different version of [tag:erlang].

Comment: Yea, my guess is the Erlang version is wrong. I use Homebrew and have Elixir working on my machine. Elixir 1.10 needs Erlang 21.0 or later. Maybe try `brew install erlang`?

Comment: I have the latest versions of Elixir (1.10.2) and Erlang (22.3) on my machine, both installed via homebrew. Have you tried using `brew uninstall` to uninstall both elixir and erlang and then `brew install elixir` again?

Comment: Also, perhaps your brew packages need updating. What does `brew outdated` tell you?